# c# Nhibernate create query with dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, nhibernate

using the folowing extention methods :

```
    public static void SetParameters(this IQuery query, List<object> Parameters) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Count(); i++) {
            query.SetParameter(i, Parameters[i]);
        }
    }
    public static IQuery SetQuery(this ISession session, string Query, object[] Parameters) {
        return session.CreateSQLQuery(Query + string.Empty + "(" + ParseExt(Parameters) + ")");
    }

    private static string ParseExt(object[] Parameters) {
        var str = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Length; i++) {
            str.Add(":" + i);
        }
        return string.Join(",", str);
    }
```

i'm creating a query :

- ```
  public IEnumerable<T> Execute<T>(string Query, params dynamic[] Parameters) {
      using (var _session = _transactionManager.GetSession()) {
          var _cmd = _session.SetQuery(Query, Parameters);
          if (Parameters != null) {
              _cmd.SetParameters(Parameters.ToList());
          }
          return _cmd.List<T>();
      }
  }
  ```

throws the following error :

```
Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based!
```

NOTE : i tried to change the index to start from 1

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `select * from dbo.OctoGetProducts`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight its added after and parsed as follow : `select * from dbo.OctoGetProducts(:0,:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7)`

Answer (score 2):

The symbol for position-parameter is not *`:xxx`* but **`?`**.

This change will work

```
private static string ParseExt(object[] Parameters) {
    var str = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Length; i++) {
        //str.Add(":" + i);
        str.Add("?"); // + i);
    }
    return string.Join(",", str);
}
```